# BLE Eddystone packet - RSSI, Tx and Distance

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Let's say this is the packet....

043e2b020103018749c6edbfd81f0201060303aafe1716aafe 00 d8 8b9cc73c3ae747ef65bc0000000015d20000bf

How to read RSSI & TX from eddystone UID packet? I understand first byte after *aafe* indicate packet type and next byte indicate Tx. But when i convert it to decimal, i get 216 which can't be power and if i take two's complement, i get -40. So is this RSSI or Tx. If i need to get both, how can i do that? How can i calculate distance from them?

Also, what are these first 25 bytes and how to decode them?

043e2b020103018749c6edbfd81f0201060303aafe1716aafe

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Jos Ryke's Beacon Cheat Sheet might help you decode this a little bit:

https://twitter.com/josryke/status/627851131046219776

The second useful thing to know is that `aafe` appears twice. The number to the left is [data type](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/).

In the [Bluetooth core specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=478726), it describes how the AD Structures repeat with Length, AD Type, AD Data

[image: AD Structure]